# PHP socket fread response takes forever

Tags: php, sockets, tcp, provisioning, epp

I want to send XML requests via EPP protocole to a registrar and get responses, the connection is successful, but when I get to `fread($fp)` , it takes forever to load.

Is there a way to make it fast and get a response from the registrar?

I am using the code bellow in a hostbill plugin.

```
 /** open socket* */
        $fp = fsockopen("tcp://registrarwebsite.com", 700, $errno, $errstr, 200);

        stream_set_blocking($fp, true);

        stream_context_set_option($fp, 'ssl', 'verify_host', true);
        stream_context_set_option($fp, 'ssl', 'verify_peer', true);
        stream_context_set_option($fp, 'ssl', 'allow_self_signed', false);
        stream_context_set_option($fp, 'ssl', 'local_cert', __DIR__ . '/ma_cert.pem');
        stream_context_set_option($fp, 'ssl', 'local_pk', __DIR__ . '/ma_key.pem');


        // $secure = stream_socket_enable_crypto($fp, true, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_CLIENT);
        // stream_set_blocking($fp, false);

        if (!$fp) {
            $this->addError('Il y a une erreur dans la connexion: ' . $errno . ' ' . $errstr);
            return false;
        } else {

            $xml = htmlentities($this->prepareXMLRequest($xml));

            fwrite($fp, $xml);

            $out = fread($fp, 1024);

            fclose($fp);

            $out1 = htmlentities($fp);

            $this->addError('<span style="color: green !important">Connexion se fait avec succes, le code retourné est : </span> ' . $out1);
```

Comment: _in a_ what?  A rocket ship?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your question?

Comment: The title: "_PHP socket fread response takes forever **in a**_", so _in a_ what? In a rocket ship, in a time machine, in a vacuum?

Comment: Ah, sorry, thank you so much ... it was just a typo. Best +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your EPP implementation is wrong (if the server supports the standard up to the letter of course), see [RFC5734](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5734) which I quote:

> 4. Data Unit Format
>
> The EPP data unit contains two fields: a 32-bit header that describes
> the total length of the data unit, and the EPP XML instance.  The
> length of the EPP XML instance is determined by subtracting four
> octets from the total length of the data unit.  A receiver must
> successfully read that many octets to retrieve the complete EPP XML
> instance before processing the EPP message.

Note also section 3 that shows when you open the TCP/TLS connection the first party to speak is the server with the `<greeting>` so as the client you first need to read that and then send your login.

Comment: Thank you so much for your precious answer, it was helpful ^^ Best +1